# RouterFunction not able to inject handler bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rx-java

I've set up a temporary github project to troubleshoot a hobby project to learn reactive java. https://github.com/mikepc/mongodb-reactive-tmp

My biggest problem is getting the router to configure properly.

Router:

```
@Configuration
public class SponsoredEventRouter {


    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(SponsoredEventHandler handler){

        return RouterFunctions
                .route(POST("/events").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::createSponsoredEvent);
    }

}
```

Handler:

```
@Slf4j
@Component

public class SponsoredEventHandler {
    private final SponsoredEventService sponsoredEventService;

    public SponsoredEventHandler(SponsoredEventService sponsoredEventService) {
        this.sponsoredEventService = sponsoredEventService;
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> createSponsoredEvent(ServerRequest req) {
        Mono<SponsoredEventRequest> newEventRequest = req.bodyToMono(SponsoredEventRequest.class);

        return ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(this.sponsoredEventService.createSponsoredEvent(newEventRequest), SponsoredEvent.class);


    }
}
```

The POM is in the project

Problems are the following:
1) IDEA is showing a red squiggly saying "Could not autowire. No beans of type 'SponsoredEventHandler' could be found." 
2) The route is not being registered. When I hit the /events endpoint, it returns a basic 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer: The packages were not aligned correctly. All of the packages were at the same level of the hierarchy. This was a devil to debug, but now I noticed it, it's working great. Thank you for anyone who read this <3